# Play multiple videos one after an other android without break

Tags: android, video

I am working on a Video player for android. How can i play a video which has more than 5 parts. How can i continuously play all the parts one after another without any break while starting next video. How can i achieve this. please guide me in this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is a way to achieve this, without going down to the NDK.
I have worked on a video app, similar to youtube with ads integration. However we did not find a way of doing a smooth transition between the ads and the content video.

There are commercial libs, which allow you to play streams even on android 2. If your videos have the same streaming type, you could try to fiddle with the m3u and merge the m3us on client side. But i have not tried it.

The most simple solution would be to preprocess and merge the videos on serverside, but depending on your use case this might not be an option.

Answer (score 0):

maybi exoPlayer can help you.
this library can concatenate multi video together.